# Loading .DLL in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, dll

I want to call a .DLL method in Eclipse. Here is my code :

```
class TestJNI1 {
          public native void LireNoVersion();
          public void a() {
              System.loadLibrary("tttt.dll");
              LireNoVersion();
          }

        }

    public GlobalAction() {
        this.setBackground(GlobalPreferences.PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        new TestJNI1().a();
    }
```

The problem is that I have this error on compilation :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: tttt.dll  at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
```

I already tried to :

- Set arguments in Eclipse
- Moving at root of project and System32 folder
- Added the folder path in native library location in Eclipse
- Changing the %PATH% in windows
- Giving the absolute path as an argument
- Trying with "tttt.dll", "./tttt.dll" and ".tttt.dll"
- Call with `System.loadLibrary(...)` and `System.load(...)`

**UPDATE**

I tried to print the `java.library.path` and get a path. I put the dll in this path and the error message is more confusing now :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\My\Exact\Path\tttt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Here is the code to print the path :

```
String property = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(property, ";");
while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.err.println(parser.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you specify an absolute path to your dll i.e `C:/tttt.dll`? Have you tried all of the following examples: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp

Comment: And do you get the same error message **when** you specifying an absolute path i.e `C:/tttt.dll`?

Comment: Do the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` could have a link with the development language of the .DLL. It's in Bordland 32bit.

Comment: No. check your Bordland 32 bit dll using `dependency walker`. It may have some win dependency.

Comment: try with giving setting VM Argument -Djava.library.path="Absolute PATH// TO // LIBRARY"

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark or put your own solution. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Library` interface in the `sun.jna` package did the trick :

```
  import com.sun.jna.Library;
  import com.sun.jna.Native;

  public class DllTest {
  public interface IDLL extends Library {
        IDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary("tttt", IDLL.class);

        int LireNoVersion(); // DWORD LireNoVersion();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IDLL sdll = IDLL.INSTANCE;

        int nover = sdll.LireNoVersion();

        System.out.println("version = " + nover + "\n");

    }

}
```

Still don't know why it didn't worked before.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem was it couldn't find the dll because it wasn't in the path.

The second problem is that it can't find the dependencies on the dll that you are using.  Your choices would seem to be

1. Copy all dependent libraries to the dll location
2. Run your code from the original dll location.

Answer (score 0):

Give the absolute path of the file

```
 try {
    System.load("C:/myapplication/application.dll");
 } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
  System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
  System.exit(1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead:

```
System.loadLibrary("tttt");
```

Comment: Still gettint that `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`, thanks for trying Dizzy.

Comment: I don't think that is invalid answer even though it did not resolve Totem's problem.

Comment: To find dependent libraries of tttt.dll, you'll have to use Dependency Viewer (which is downloadable). 
Another thing: hope you are using 64-bit JDK (couldn't ask this on original post).